MOSCAP retention time
I am trying to understand how MOSCAPs behave to know how to use them.
I generated the figure below by connecting an NMOS in a MOSCAP configuration (source, drain, and body shorted), sweeping the gate from -1.2 to 1.2 and measuring the capacitance. The figure I got is expected since the gate capacitance is supposed to be ideally \$C_{ox}\$ for very negative and very positive values of gate voltage.

I wanted to understand how long the MOSCAP can retain its voltage. I applied a fixed voltage \$C_{init}\$ to the gate, cut-off the supply, and measure how long it takes the voltage to drop to \$\frac{1}{e} \cdot C_{init}\$. I did this for voltages between -1.2 and 1.2 and got the plot below. This plot is not what I was expecting. I was expecting the retention time to be longer for large voltages since the capacitance is large for large voltages. Large capacitance translates to large time constants. What I got is the complete opposite. Why is this so?

